# Spring: RequestBody marshalling on POST of data specifying xml namespace

Tags: java, xml, spring, rest

I am having a problem marshalling a RequestBody when the parent class has a namespace.

Class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "blah")
public class Test {
    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
       this.id = id;
    }

}
```

XML:
`<blah>`
`<id>23333</id>`
`</blah>`

Code:

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/blah", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE }, produces = { MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE})
public String getBlah( @RequestBody Test request ) throws Exception
{
    assert(null != request.getId());
    return "blah";
}
```

This works fine.  However, if I use `@XmlRootElement(name = "blah", namespace="home")` on the class, and `<blah xmlns="home">` in the request, the Test class constructs, but it's ID value is never set.

I'm at a loss.

Comment: did you found any solution ??

Answer (score 0):

Before **public void setId**  method add annotation @XmlElement

Comment: This could be a comment only. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).